# For Content Security problem my stripe isn't running

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

When I am trying to run stripe my browser show me

> "Refused to load the script 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/' because it
> violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src
> 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so
> 'script-src' is used as a fallback. "

I have tried using meta tag but the problem didn't solve

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to relax Content Security Policy with meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131814/how-to-relax-content-security-policy-with-meta-tag). TL;DR - it's likely your server is sending the directive mentioned in the error message as part of a `Content-Security-Policy` HTTP header, which would overrule anything you have in your CSP `meta` tag. The solution here is to reconfigure your server to send headers explicitly allowing scripts to be loaded from `js.stripe.com`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was happened because i bundle all of my code after then i write the code script(src="link").
At the end i mean after writing all of the code you have to bundle all of your code.

Answer (score 0):

[Stripe Integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYdFS.png)

Use Import Command to add Stripe.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).